# crashes while attaching VS code container to running container

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am running open source code in a docker container and trying to connect vscode to that.

Remote container extension of VS Code crashed multiple time while attaching to a docker container. Below is the container log. What could be the issue, and how can it be fixed? Can we install vs code extension to container manually after logging to container using "docker exec" if yes. how?

```
t: Resolving Remote
[64 ms] Setting up container: /zen_hugle
[69 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container /zen_hugle
[105 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[106 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[161 ms] Server API version: 1.41
[162 ms] Start: Inspecting container
[162 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container 5f86e464bff26f794d55499d35e18c186e655d3709173be7697176b2a4402176
[198 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[201 ms] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[280 ms] x86_64
[280 ms] 
[280 ms] Start: Run in container: (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
[282 ms] NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
[282 ms] 
[282 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[285 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server
[286 ms] 
[286 ms] 
[286 ms] Start: Run in container: test ! -f '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[287 ms] 
[287 ms] 
[287 ms] Exit code 1
[288 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json
[289 ms] 
[289 ms] cat: /root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json: No such file or directory
[289 ms] Exit code 1
[290 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
[291 ms] 
[291 ms] 
[291 ms] Exit code 1
[292 ms] Installing VS Code Server for commit 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
[292 ms] Start: Downloading VS Code Server
[293 ms] 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3 linux-x64 stable 
[913594 ms] Start: Installing VS Code Server
[913595 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3_1643291354534
[913601 ms] 
[913602 ms] 
[913718 ms] Start: Run in container: (dd iflag=fullblock bs=8192 count=6542 2>/dev/null; dd iflag=fullblock bs=3733 count=1 2>/dev/null) | tar --no-same-owner -xz -C /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3_1643291354534
[916818 ms] 
[916818 ms] 
[916819 ms] Start: Run in container: mv -n /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3_1643291354534/* /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3 && rmdir /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3_1643291354534
[916826 ms] 
[916827 ms] 
[916828 ms] Start: Launching Remote-Containers helper.
[916829 ms] ssh-agent: SSH_AUTH_SOCK in container (/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-b33b309ad2ab0c801b7e9e5c2937d02d5c4f518c.sock) forwarded to local host (/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh).
[916829 ms] Start: Run: gpgconf --list-dir agent-extra-socket
[916839 ms] /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
[916839 ms] 
[916839 ms] Start: Run in container: gpgconf --list-dir agent-socket
[916841 ms] 
[916841 ms] /bin/sh: 11: gpgconf: not found
[916842 ms] Exit code 127
[916843 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[916851 ms] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[916856 ms] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/bash
[916867 ms] Start: Run in container: cat <<'EOF-/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-b33b309ad2ab0c801b7e9e5c2937d02d5c4f518c.js' >/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-b33b309ad2ab0c801b7e9e5c2937d02d5c4f518c.js
[916874 ms] Start: Run in container: # Test for /root/.ssh/known_hosts and ssh
[916885 ms] ssh not found
[916886 ms] 
[916886 ms] Exit code 1
[916887 ms] Start: Run in container: command -v git >/dev/null 2>&1 && git config --system --replace-all credential.helper '!f() { /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-b33b309ad2ab0c801b7e9e5c2937d02d5c4f518c.js $*; }; f' || true
[916893 ms] 
[916893 ms] 
[916894 ms] Start: Preparing Extensions
[916899 ms] Start: Run in container: test ! -f '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.installExtensionsMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.installExtensionsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[916901 ms] 
[916902 ms] 
[916908 ms] Extensions cache, install extensions: None
[916908 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache && ls /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache || true
[916909 ms] 
[916910 ms] 
[916914 ms] Extensions cache, copy to remote: None
[916914 ms] Start: Run in container: for pid in `cd /proc && ls -d [0-9]*`; do { echo $pid ; readlink /proc/$pid/cwd ; readlink /proc/$pid/ns/mnt ; cat /proc/$pid/stat | tr "
[916993 ms] Start: Starting VS Code Server
[917107 ms] 
[917108 ms] 
[917108 ms] Start: Run in container: cat <<'EOF-/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-b33b309ad2ab0c801b7e9e5c2937d02d5c4f518c.js' >/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-b33b309ad2ab0c801b7e9e5c2937d02d5c4f518c.js_1643291358047
[917125 ms] 
[917125 ms] 
[917143 ms] Start: Run in Container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3/server.sh --log debug --force-disable-user-env --use-host-proxy --port 0 --extensions-download-dir /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache --start-server --disable-websocket-compression
[917404 ms] 

*
* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
* as described in the license https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/license
*

Extension host agent listening on 42325

[917405 ms] Start: Run in container: echo 42325 >'/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.devport-899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3'
[917406 ms] 
[917406 ms] 
[917407 ms] Port forwarding for container port 42325 starts listening on local port.
[917410 ms] Port forwarding local port 42325 to container port 42325
[917411 ms] Start: Run in container: test ! -f '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.onCreateCommandMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.onCreateCommandMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[917421 ms] userEnvProbe PATHs:
Probe:     '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
Container: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
Merged:    '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
[917423 ms] 
[917423 ms] 
[917424 ms] Start: Run in container: test ! -f '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.updateContentCommandMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.updateContentCommandMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[917427 ms] 
[917428 ms] 
[917428 ms] Start: Run in container: test ! -f '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.postCreateCommandMarker' && set -o noclobber && mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.postCreateCommandMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[917431 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch installed extensions
[917433 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch machine settings
[917536 ms] 
[917540 ms] 
[917549 ms] Start: Run in container: command -v git >/dev/null 2>&1 && git config --global --replace-all credential.helper '!f() { /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-b33b309ad2ab0c801b7e9e5c2937d02d5c4f518c.js $*; }; f' || true
[917625 ms] 
[917625 ms] 
[917633 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && [ "$(cat '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.postStartCommandMarker' 2>/dev/null)" != '2022-01-27T13:16:41.401270814Z' ] && echo '2022-01-27T13:16:41.401270814Z' > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.postStartCommandMarker'
[917667 ms] Port forwarding connection from 47428 > 42325 > 42325 in the container.
[917676 ms] Start: Run in container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3/node -e 
[917758 ms] 
[917759 ms] 
[917904 ms] [13:49:18] Extension host agent started.
[918783 ms] Port forwarding connection from 47432 > 42325 > 42325 in the container.
[918784 ms] Start: Run in container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3/node -e 
[919066 ms] [13:49:20] [::ffff:127.0.0.1][18dea54c][ManagementConnection] New connection established.
[919713 ms] [13:49:20] [::ffff:127.0.0.1][a4567d34][ExtensionHostConnection] New connection established.
[919722 ms] [13:49:20] [::ffff:127.0.0.1][a4567d34][ExtensionHostConnection] <274> Launched Extension Host Process.
[926920 ms] Extensions cache, remote removals: None
[978544 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch installed extensions
[978731 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch machine settings
[986927 ms] Extensions cache, remote removals: None
[1039078 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch installed extensions
[1039256 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch machine settings
[1046934 ms] Extensions cache, remote removals: None
[1099652 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch installed extensions
[1099836 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch machine settings
[1106943 ms] Extensions cache, remote removals: None
[1160226 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch installed extensions
[1160427 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch machine settings
[1166955 ms] Extensions cache, remote removals: None
[1220655 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch installed extensions
[1220891 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch machine settings
[1226960 ms] Extensions cache, remote removals: None
[1281137 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch installed extensions
[1281379 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch machine settings
[1286966 ms] Extensions cache, remote removals: None
[1341610 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch installed extensions
[1341959 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c # Watch machine settings
[1346973 ms] Extensions cache, remote removals: None
```

Comment: This is also occurring in Docker containers-especially when Extensions is clicked on in Python flies.